# How can I fix refused to connection error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, pop-os

I am using `PopOS 22.04 LTS` and `FortiClient` to access a web page. when I send a ping to this IP on the terminal, everything works well as below.

```
64 bytes from 10.190.16.13: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=27.2 ms
64 bytes from 10.190.16.13: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=28.1 ms
64 bytes from 10.190.16.13: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=27.8 ms
64 bytes from 10.190.16.13: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=28.0 ms
^C
--- 10.190.16.13 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 27.224/27.788/28.129/0.353 ms
```

But when I copy and paste that IP into the browser, I am not able to access it. That works on Windows but I couldn't make the things work on PopOS. Is there someone who can help, please?

`Web browser error as below`

**This site can’t be reached**

**IP** refused to connect.

Try:

Checking the connection

- Checking the connection
- Checking the proxy and the firewall

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Are you running windows and PopOS from the same machine/same IP? What is the device you're trying to talk to? What does FortiClient have to do with it?

Comment: I have two laptops. One is Windows other one is Linux. I have no idea what's the device. I am just trying to access GitLab with that link and without FortiClient, I cannot access their services—for example, GitLab, e-mail services, management software, etc.